# Printing a binary search tree with commas and spaces in C

Tags: c, recursion, printf, binary-search-tree, binary-search

I am struggling to print a binary search tree like the below output (in-order traversal):

```
2, 3, 6, 9
```

the output I get:

```
2, 3, 6, 9,
```

The code I have:

```
void inorder(struct node* root)
{   
    if (root != NULL) {
        inorder(root->left_node);
        printf("%d, ", root->value);
        inorder(root->right_node);
    }
     
}
```

how struct node is implemented:

```
struct node {
    int value;           
    struct node *left_node;  
    struct node *right_node; 

};
```

I am not sure how to get rid of the comma and the space characters after the last element.

Comment: Please note that it is not polite to ask questions, get some help, and then delete the question before anything gets upvoted.  (For 10k users: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72823329/, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72811337/ (which was deleted and reasked as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72812564, which is not yet deleted), to list two questions, though there probably aren't many more yet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The theory is that you have to print the `,`  only if you are sure that the leaf you are printing is not the last one.

Thus, you need a way to tell your nodes (sub-trees) whether they contain the "last" leaf of your tree. One way of doing is to create another function which takes one more parameter:

```
static void inorder_haslastleaf(struct node* root, int haslastleaf) {
  if (root != NULL) {
    /* Print the left sub-tree, we are guaranteed it can't contain the last leaf
     * because the current node will be printed right after. */
    inorder_haslastleaf(root->left_node, 0);
    printf("%d", root->value);
    /* Now, we have to print comma if and only if we are sure that
     * some nodes will be printed after it. We can make sure of that
     * thanks to the haslastleaf flag. */
    if(!haslastleaf || root->right_node != NULL)
      printf(", ");
    /* Finally, print the right sub-tree. Pass back haslastleaf to it
     * to notify whether it contains the last leaf or not  */
    inorder_haslastleaf(root->right_node, haslastleaf);
  }
}

void inorder(struct node* root)
{
  /* Of course, the main tree contains the last leaf */
  inorder_haslastleaf(root, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need to print a `,`  if the right node is not null. With that in mind, split the `printf()` into two calls and check whether the next node is null or not.

```
void inorder(struct node* root)
{   
    if (root != NULL) {
        inorder(root->left_node);
        printf("%d", root->value);
        if (root->right_node)
             printf(", ");
        inorder(root->right_node);
    }         
}
```

Comment: your answer prints ```2, 45, 8```

Comment: That (`2, 45, 8`) bears no resemblance to the desired output mentioned in the question (`2, 3, 6, 9`), @ferocioussprouts122; how can we tell what's up?  You'll probably want to output a newline at the end of the output.

Comment: the answer above gives the output ```2, 36, 9``` instead of ```2, 3, 6, 9```

Comment: Thank you, @ferocioussprouts122; that's a clearer explanation of the problem.

Comment: A plausible (but as yet untested) solution would be to add `if (root->left_node) printf(", ");` after `inorder(root->left_node);`.  That's essentially symmetric with the other condition — `if (root->right_node) printf(", ");` — and symmetric code is often (but not always) good code.